# Define response structure in Adonisjs with Middleware

Tags: javascript, response, middleware, adonis.js

I want to define the response structure of my requests in the simplest way, and the first thing that comes in my mind to do this is a middleware.
My endpoints are returning the response content correctly:

`{{base_url}}/users` returns a list of users:

```
{
  [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "name": "some name"
      [...]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do (in all requests) is to add the fields `status` and `data` (or any other I'd like to add), like this:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "name": "some name"
      [...]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've created a middleware that waits for the resolution but I'm not able to get the content nor add some property to it.

```
   [...]
   async handle ({request, response}, next) {
     await next()
     const content = response._lazyBody.content 
     content.status = response.response.statusCode
   }
   [...]
```

I know this will not work but I want something similar to this. I've looked in Adonis docs and forum, but no answers fit to my needs.

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Response` By extending the core. The simplest way is to create a file inside `start` folder and name it `hooks.js` and copy and paste the content below inside it:

```js
const { hooks } = use('@adonisjs/ignitor')
const Response = use('Adonis/Src/Response')

hooks.after.providersBooted(() => {
  Response.macro('customJson', function (status, data) {
    this.status(status).json({
      status,
      data
    })
  })
})
```

this piece of code extends the `Response` module and add `customJson` method to it which takes two arguments, `status` and `data`, and send them back to the client.

And here you can see how to use it:

```js
Route.get('/users', async ({ response }) => {
  let status = ''// whatever you want
  let data = ''// whatever you want
  return response.customJson(status, data)
})
```

Comment: I really appreciate that, it's 80% what I was looking for. One more thing before I approve, can I get the statusCode from the request itself instead of hard coding one? Like `return response.customJson(response.statusCode, data)`

Comment: You’re welcome. There is no ‘status’ param in request module! Response status totally corresponds to the response itself and depend on it. If you want to respond an ‘Unauthorized Access’ you should set the status to 403 and so on so forth. So you need to hard code it whenever you want to use it.

Comment: If you get `Cannot find module 'Adonis/Src/Response` Error, put `const Response = use('Adonis/Src/Response')` line in callback of `providersBooted` .

Comment: How to use customJson for a Controller/method closure?

Comment: @AymaneShuichi As I said just use `response.customJson(status, data)`